# Capitalize the string in the options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very small silly  doubt .

i have a line
<%= select_tag "kind", options_from_collection_for_select(@blogs, :id, :name) %>

this shows the blog name in small case , how to capitalize it here ..

I am using rails 2.3.11

Comment: If you just want to capitalize for showing, you can use css, otherwise, create a virtual attribute from name and use that instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend creating a virtual attribute, say `display_name` that looks something like:

```
def display_name
  name.capitalize
end
```

And your select tag will now look like:

```
<%= select_tag "kind", options_from_collection_for_select(@blogs, :id, :display_name) %>
```

Hope that helps.